# Function call in critical section of semaphores

Tags: c, critical-section

I am using semaphores to surround a critical section of code that is removing an `int` from a shared array among multiple processes.

My question is if in the critical section of code I have a function call to a helper function will it still be protected?

So for example if I had code that followed this outline:

```
  mutex_lock();
  some_helper_function_call();
  mutex_unlock();
```

Will the function still be protected with these locks or not? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is your code under *mutex lock* and *unlock* is protected. So in this case, `some_helper_function_call();` is protected by *mutex*.

Answer (score 1):

it is. it seems you don't really know what a semaphore is. it's just an integer, stored somewhere in the memory. so if you lock it, its value will remain unchanged unless you unlock it.